# How to read this code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have found below code on Internet and trying to make sense of it.

Not sure how can we use value to i when it is assigned value later in the loop.

further also appreciate if someone can explain how it works i.e. assigned back for each iteration

```
>>> import pprint
>>> ds = dict((chr(i), range(i, i+5)) for i in range(65,70))
```

Comment: It should have been better as `ds = {chr(i): range(i,i+5) for i in range(65,70)}`. Why create a generator then a dict when you can create a dict directly?

Comment: @Billiska: Because dict comprehensions weren't introduced until Python 2.7.

Comment: `pprint` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking at a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). The part before `for` is executed in a loop defined by the `for` expression.

The generator expression produces a sequence of `key, value` pairs, which the `dict()` constructor uses to build a dictionary. You could read the code as having the same result as:

```
ds = {}
for i in range(65, 70):
    ds[chr(i)], range(i, i+5)
```

In Python 2.7 and Python 3, you can use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) as well:

```
ds = {chr(i): range(i, i+5) for i in range(65,70)}
```

The result would be the same; you define `key: value` expressions to build the dictionary from the loop.

In generator expressions, as well as (list, dict or set) comprehensions you can use multiple, nested loops, and add `if` statements to filter the data. These are defined in nesting order; outermost loop first:

```
result = [i ** 2 for foo in range(10) if foo % 2 == 0 for i in range(foo)]
```

can be read as:

```
result = []
for foo in range(10):
    if foo % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(foo):
            result.append(i ** 2)
```

See [this article](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#list-comprehensions) for a quick intoduction.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to create an iterator of tuples, which it then passes to the `dict` constructor to build a new dictionary. It helps if you look at what the generator is doing by converting it to a list:

```
>>> list((chr(i), range(i, i+5)) for i in range(65,70))
[('A', [65, 66, 67, 68, 69]), ('B', [66, 67, 68, 69, 70]), ('C', [67, 68, 69, 70, 71]), ('D', [68, 69, 70, 71, 72]), ('E', [69, 70, 71, 72, 73])]
```

Remember that if you pass [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) a list of tuples, the first element of each tuple will be used as the key and the second as the value:

```
>>> dict([('key1', 'val1'), ('key2', 'val2')])
{'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1'}
```

Other than that, the only thing you need to know to understand that expression is what [`chr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) and [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) do.